# request.getParameter() method return null with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to invoke doPost method in servlet with an ajax call yet the request.GetParameter(textboxID) returns null value. The doPost method is well invoked but prints null everytime. below is my jsp and servlet. I have been working on it for weeks yet haven't figured out what is wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script src="/javascript/basic.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
            alert("jquery invoked");
            $.ajax({
                url : 'myservlet',
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : $("form").serialize,
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data.isValid) {
                        $('#output').html(data.filePath2);
                        $('#output').slidedown(499);
                    } else {
                        alert('Data is not valid!');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });     
    });  
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="txtFilepath"  name="txtFilepath"/> <br>
        <input type="Submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="output"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**servlet**

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String filepath = request.getParameter("txtFilepath");
    System.out.println(filepath);

    map.put("isValid", true);
    map.put("filePath2", filepath);
    write(response, map);
}

private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis at the **serialize** call:

```
data : $("form").serialize()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are implementing POST inside servlet and calling GET from jQuery ajax.  Try using `type:'POST'` instead of `type:'GET'` inside your javascript function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i was trying if it worked on the get method but forgot to change it before posting here. turned out i was missing the parenthesis after serialize ()

Answer (score 1):

Add this `doGet()` method to your servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException { 

doPost(request,response);

}
```

In jquery you should correct this `data : $("form").serialize` to 
`data : $("form").serialize()`

`.serialize()` is a Method.

And most important point is `<input type="Submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">` should be

`<input type="Button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">` , The Button should be of type `Button` not type `Submit` . It will always fail, if it is of Type `Submit`.

OR

Add following line Before Ajax call `e.preventDefault()`, it will cancel the Default behaviour of submit button.

So it should be

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        alert("jquery invoked");
        $.ajax({... Rest of the code
```